# Dell keyboard NSK-DJ F01 versus NSK-DJ301

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-vostro

I have a Dell vostro 3500 keyboard and its model number (which is typed at the back of the keyboard when i removed it) is NSK-DJ F01. And i found an online keyboard on amazon which have a model number of NSK-DJ301*. so if i buy the model NSK-DJ301 will it work on my laptop which have its keyboard model number NSK-DJ F01 ?. and what are the differences between NSK-DJ F01 & NSK-DJ301 keyboards ?

Answer (score 0):

Not supposed to be shopping recommendations here, but, one of the advantages of buying from Amazon is that you have 30 days to return it.  Check the description carefully and see if your model is listed.

However, as far as I can see, it looks like the difference is the backlighting.

Comment: i am actully asking for the technical differences between the two types of keyboard. and if both will work for me or not ?. and i reference amazon just to give an example.so you mean that NSK-DJ301 comes with back light , while NSK-DJ F01 does not. second question my current laptop does not have backlight in the keyboard, so will the backlight keyboard work well inside my laptop ?

Comment: As far as I can see, they are the same except for the backlight;  the non-backlight one is typically cheaper.  I see plenty of posts about people upgrading their laptops with the backlit version, but this is why I'd always recommend buying from somewhere that it can be returned.  Also Dell has far fewer actual keyboard models than laptops which they fit.